# Running MiniZinc in Python through the native interface in Win10

Tags: python, minizinc

I am trying to call **MiniZinc** through python while using the native python interface.

The interface is **working** under **Ubuntu** but **not in Win10**.

The code I am using is the following which is found on the official website of MiniZinc [A Basic Example](https://minizinc-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#a-basic-example)

I have created the nqueens.mzn file and added it to the project's directory.

The error I am getting is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sallo/PycharmProjects/MiniZincTest/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    result = instance.solve()
  File "C:\Users\Sallo\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\minizinc\instance.py", line 99, in solve
    return asyncio.run(coroutine)
  File "C:\Users\Sallo\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Sallo\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 579, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Sallo\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\minizinc\CLI\instance.py", line 394, in solve_async
    **kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\Sallo\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\minizinc\CLI\instance.py", line 310, in solutions
    proc = await self._driver.create_process(cmd, solver=self._solver)
  File "C:\Users\Sallo\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\minizinc\CLI\driver.py", line 170, in create_process
    stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
  File "C:\Users\Sallo\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\subprocess.py", line 217, in create_subprocess_exec
    stderr=stderr, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Sallo\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1529, in subprocess_exec
    bufsize, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sallo\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 458, in _make_subprocess_transport
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Here is the code:

```
from minizinc import Instance, Model, Solver

# Load n-Queens model from file
nqueens = Model("./nqueens.mzn")
# Find the MiniZinc solver configuration for Gecode
gecode = Solver.lookup("gecode")
# Create an Instance of the n-Queens model for Gecode
instance = Instance(gecode, nqueens)
# Assign 4 to n
instance["n"] = 4
result = instance.solve()
# Output the array q
print(result["q"])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This problem was caused by the limited support for the `asyncio` library. Until Python 3.8, the default event loop did not support the functionality that the MiniZinc Python library uses. This problem was reported on the MiniZinc Python Issue tacker (https://gitlab.com/minizinc/minizinc-python/issues/14) and was fixed soon after.

Yesterday marked the day of a new release for MiniZinc Python, version 0.2.1, which included this fix and some small changes. That it now works using Python 3.6 should be due to the fact that re-downloading the package will have updated the MiniZinc Python version from 0.2.0 to 0.2.1.

Comment: so this means that it is now runnable under python 3.7 and 3.8?

Comment: Yes, Python 3.8 should have already been working, but 3.7 should be working after yesterday's fix.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution by accident.

I downgraded from python 3.7 to 3.6 and now it works in windows too...